# Moving two pieces together

Tags: rules, pawns

Can one open by moving **two** pawns at a time, one square forward for each? (I hope you don't think I'm being funny-I was taught this when playing at school and have always played with this option).

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question: The possibility to move two different pawns one step each from their base position is part of many orally transmitted rulesets. Of course, the answer is no for standard chess (and has been so for at least one and a half century).

Answer (score 7):

Not in a regular chess.

There are some "homemade" rules at least in some parts of the world that allow you to open with two moves (so only at the start of the game), but those are not used on any serious level.

So no, you can't move two pawns in the same move.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can either:

1. Move one pawn forwards 2 squares, provided it is the pawn's first move, or
2. Move one pawn forward one square, unless it is blocked by another piece
3. Make a capture, either normally or *en passant*

If you want to learn more, there is a great [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess) article on the rules.